# Using wildcard in AllowedCorsOrigin of the IdentityServer

Tags: identity-server, wildcards

Is there a way to use wildcard in **AllowedCorsOrigin** of the IdentityServer. I want to allow all the sites to access the Sitecore CMS. I tried the following which didn't work.

```
<AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>*.site.com</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
```

One way is to add all the sites in the **AllowedCorsOrigin** but I want a new site to be added automatically rather than entering the site manually in the **AllowedCorsOrigin**.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try updating the `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` information using a PowerShell script?

Comment: Using the Sitecore Powershell Extension?. Will this cause the app pool recycle? @SumitBhatia

Comment: I am not sure that you need to do this but if you are manually updating the config then a script can do that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcards are not currently supported by Identity Server. There was a [similar request in the Identity Server GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3765) and the response was:

> Wildcards in URLs are always dangerous from a security point of view.
>
> If you need that particular feature and think you can implement it securely for your environment, please use our extensibility points to do it yourself. That's why they exist.

So you can either list all your domains in the config under `<AllowedCorsOriginsGroup>` or write a custom implementation of `ICorsPolicyService` and define the method `Task<bool> IsOriginAllowedAsync(string origin)` to meet your requirements - it should return `true` if the origin is allowed and `false` otherwise. Then you can register the class in Identity Server dependency injection container:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>((container) => {
    return new CustomCorsPolicyService();
});
```

Here is Identity Server documentation for custom Cors Policy services: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/cors.html#custom-cors-policy-service

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the wildcard but You can use a pipe sign and write as below:

```
<AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>abc.site.com|abc2.site.com|abc3.site.com|abc4.site.com</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
```

Comment: Thanks Himmat, I know about this way of adding sites but I wanted to make a dynamic entry so that when a new site is created, I would not need to add a new site manually in the AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1

Comment: You can separate the project for SI and write a patch file and use the code to update dynamically this config.

Comment: the patch config will cause the app pool recycle.